# jQuery .text() grabbing text that matches condition

Tags: jquery, dom, css-selectors

Once the user triggers an action, h1.text() has to be the same as h2.text().

```
$('h1').text($('h2').text());
```

The problem is that h2 has some spans and hidden spans inside. E.g.:

```
<h2>Countries: <span class="ec">Ecuador</span> <span class="cl hidden">Chile</span></h2>
```

**h1** needs to be:

```
Countries: Ecuador
```

Chile should be left out because it is inside a span with the hidden class. I know this can be achieved with conditions somehow. Any ideas?

Comment: Actually, Ecuador is in the hidden class ;)

Comment: @musefan hehe sorry, fixed that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) the `h2` element (so we don't mess up the original), then [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) and [remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) all the `span.hidden` elements, then get the text back (using [end](http://api.jquery.com/end/) to go back up the jquery chain from the removed hidden spans back to the h2) and apply it to `h1`:

```
$('h1').text($('h2').clone().find('span.hidden').remove().end().text())
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mhUEr/1/

Comment: Doesn't work. With the provided code (noting as per musefan that the code describe is not the code provided; Ecuador is the hidden one), you will end up with two instances of "Countries: Chile"

Comment: @GregPettit, I don't understand your objection. The discrepancy between code provided and code described was obviously just a typo (the OP already fixed it), and I don't know what you mean by "you will end up with two instances". See the jsFiddle. The code works.

Comment: @GregPettit, are you maybe looking at the jquery `clone`? Clone doens't make a copy in the DOM, it makes a copy in memory.

Comment: @BenLee First, there was no fiddle when I replied. Second, the OP hadn't fixed the typo. I ran it in a fiddle of my own and it failed (making not two identical instances, but an h1 and an h2 both containing "Countries: Chile") hence the objection. It simply didn't work; no need to be offended.

Comment: @GregPettit, I wasn't offended, I just genuinely didn't understand the objection.